# Reverting a transposed array to original state with language variables

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, content-management-system, multilingual

I have a query result for pages as follow:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [lang] => en
        [id_page] => 113
        [url] => pageurl_in_english
        [title] => Page Name in English
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
        [lang] => fr
        [id_page] => 113
        [url] => pageurl_in_french
        [title] => Page Name in French

    )

)
```

I wrote a function to revert this array back to original state when form is submitted.

Original state is:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [url] => Array
            (
                [fr] => pageurl_in_french
                [en] => pageurl_in_english
            )

        [title] => Array
            (
                [fr] => Page Name in French
                [en] => Page Name in English
            )
      )
)
```

The function supposed to revert it back;

```
function ml_back_to_form($data,$fields,$languages)
{    
  $result = array();   

  foreach ($fields as $field) 
  {
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($languages as $lang)
    {
      $result[$i][$field][$lang] = $data[$i][$field];
    }
    $i++; 
  }    
  return $result;
}
```

languages array comes in order with fr,en (based on desired lang order in lang table), but pages array comes in order en,fr.  Function revert it back to current state but write all to english values. I am making a mistake here but been blind so can't see it. Thanks for any help.

If the function is fictioned in a wrong manner, new advises are always welcomed.

I edited then function to last workinh copy. Result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
      (
        [lang] => Array
            (
                [fr] => en
                [en] => en
            )

        [url] => Array
            (
                [fr] => pageurl_in_english
                [en] => pageurl_in_english
            )

        [title] => Array
            (
                [fr] => Page name in English
                [en] => Page name in English
            )

       )

)
```

Arrays provided in function:

`$data` is the first array in this question, results from db.

`$fields`:

```
 $fields = array(
            'lang',
            'url',
            'title'
      );
```

`$languages`:

```
Array
(
   [0] => fr
   [1] => en
)
```

Comment: Just a small point but your if statement in your second loop is using the assignment operator (=) rather than a comparison operator (e.g. ==). I'm not sure if this is the cause of your problem though.

Comment: I tried to replace it with `==` and gives undefined index errors with an empty array. I think it is not the problem.

Comment: If statement removed to keep the minds open. Above is lst working copy but with wrong results. Results are also added.

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of the structures of the arrays that are being passed to the function ($data, $fields and $languages)?

Comment: @Dan Murfitt, I have added passed arrays into my question. Hope you may help.

Comment: if my function makes the thing harder in anyway, a new approach to turn first array of this question to the seconds is also workable for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help:

```
function ml_back_to_form($data,$fields,$languages)
{    
    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $item)
    {
        $i=0;
        foreach ($fields as $field)
        {
            //Store the data from the field in an array
            if (in_array($item['lang'], $languages))
            $result[$i][$field][$item['lang']] = $item[$field];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Note: this function requires that the elements of `$fields` are present in the `$data` array.

Comment: works fine. Thank you fy contribution. Is there any alternative we can use instead of `in_array`?

Comment: Glad it worked. Possibly - are you looking to refactor the algorithm or do you need to just specifically avoid `in_array()`?

Comment: well I am not a pro because I will say that just trying to avoid `in_array()`. Reason is completely my own experiences that array searching is something that may bring trouble when it comes to deal with large set of records. That's why I prefer `isset` like functions wherever avilable. This is not a fact, just my low-level opinion.